# how does one use a created column as input to group by in SQL?

Tags: sql, datetime, group-by, sql-server-2017

I am creating a timeregistry in SQL and almost have created the desired view.

What I need is a view with 1 row per date + employee and the first and last recorded activity of that day. I use DATEFROMPARTS first to extract the date. I have used the "group by" statement to filter out duplicate date + employee combinations. unfortunately, this only works with 2 existing columns and thus not the created date-column. I have added a table in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c5f06/13 and my try to solve it. ( I also tried "group by date, name having count(concat(date, name)) = 1) could someone please help me?

## BUILD SCHEMA

```
CREATE TABLE employees(
  id int not null,
  name varchar(25) not null,
  dt DateTime not null,
  action varchar(10) not null,
  primary key(id));
  
INSERT INTO employees
VALUES
('1', 'a', '2022-06-13 17:00:00', 'out'),
('2', 'a', '2022-06-13 12:30:00', 'in'),
('3', 'a', '2022-06-13 12:00:00', 'out'),
('4', 'a', '2022-06-13 9:00:00', 'in'),
('5', 'b', '2022-06-13 19:00:00', 'out'),
('6', 'b', '2022-06-13 9:00:00', 'in'),
('7', 'b', '2022-06-14 18:00:00', 'out'),
('8', 'b', '2022-06-14 8:00:00', 'in'),
('9', 'noname', '2022-06-14 0:00:00', 'in');
```

## RUN SQL

```
select
DATEFROMPARTS(year(dt), month(dt), day(dt)) as date,
name,
min(dt) over(partition by Datepart(dy, dt), name) as first,
max(dt) over(partition by Datepart(dy, dt), name) as last,
concat(year(dt), month(dt), day(dt), name) as thiscolumnshouldonlyhaveuniquevalues
from employees
where name <> 'noname'
group by dt, name having count(concat(year(dt), month(dt), day(dt), name))= 1
order by date asc, name asc
```

[image]

Comment: I can see in the results  lot of duplicates. Without getting too much deep into your query results.. `DISTINCT` does not solve your issue?

Comment: Tag your database pls

Comment: Your link to fiddle is empty and your query returns error ?

Comment: @VBoka: maybe you use a different SQL version? I selected MS SQL server 2017 in the top left corner.

Comment: Hi @Bende what top left corner ? As I have told you in my  comments your link is empty and MySQL 5.6 is selected when you click on it. Also, you can tag your database where you have tagged sql, datatime and group-by and most important one , the database, you did not.

Comment: @VBoka What is tagging and why do I need this? The link works fine on my system.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245556/discussion-between-vboka-and-bende).

Comment: Hi @Bende, it would be nice if you choose the correct answer and accept it. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for your problem is that you need to use `DISTINCT`.

```
select distinct
DATEFROMPARTS(year(dt), month(dt), day(dt)) as date,
name,
min(dt) over(partition by Datepart(dy, dt), name) as first,
max(dt) over(partition by Datepart(dy, dt), name) as last,
concat(year(dt), month(dt), day(dt), name) as thiscolumnshouldonlyhaveuniquevalues
from employees
where name <> 'noname'
group by dt, name having count(concat(year(dt), month(dt), day(dt), name))= 1
order by date asc, name asc
```

Comment: DISTINCT, GROUP BY and then a having clause? This seems to be something too much ;)

Comment: Without going deep into the query results or optimization - there were a lot of duplicates :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make few changes in your query like -

1. Use aggregate function instead of Window function.
2. Get rid of Having clause.
3. I have updated the GROUP BY clause also.

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(dt), MONTH(dt), DAY(dt)) AS date,
       name,
       MIN(dt) AS first,
       MAX(dt) AS last,
       CONCAT(YEAR(dt), MONTH(dt), DAY(dt), name) as thiscolumnshouldonlyhaveuniquevalues
  FROM employees
 WHERE name <> 'noname'
 GROUP BY YEAR(dt), MONTH(dt), DAY(dt), name
 ORDER BY date asc, name asc;
```

[Demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1d66ded8775dc12257b463b569f47cf1)

Comment: Can I ask you how do you know this works ? Thanks!

Comment: @VBoka, Updated the answer with dbfiddle.

Comment: Hi @AnkitBajpai, how do you know it is SQLServer 2019 ?

Comment: As per my knowledge, DATEFROMPARTS is only supported by SQL SERVER. Is there any other DB that supports this function? Even if this is not SQL Server, Query is ANSI standard and might give a basic idea to OP to proceed futher.

Comment: You do not understand my point, a you can see the OP now has a third solution in mind. My point is: OP should at least tag a DB - it would be nice. I am not sure and I believe you are not sure about the DATEFROMPARTS is it supported anywhere else...

Comment: @VBoka, I completely agree. He should mention a DB without fail, But as a community its not our only goal to provide a sure and certain working example. If we can give a working idea to OP upon which he can achieve his end goal, sometimes that's also enough which I did.

Answer (score 0):

Bogner Roys tip and Ankits Bajpai's answers made me rethink the group by clause, and the following (added distinct, removed group by) seems to do exactly as I desire.

```
select distinct
DATEFROMPARTS(year(dt), month(dt), day(dt)) as date,
name,
min(dt) over(partition by Datepart(dy, dt), name) as first,
max(dt) over(partition by Datepart(dy, dt), name) as last,
concat(year(dt), month(dt), day(dt), name) as thiscolumnshouldonlyhaveuniquevalues
from employees
where name <> 'noname'
order by date asc, name asc
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is keyword distinct.
Group by is used when you have to apply aggregate operators to each group.

Also, do not name your columns or their aliases as data types keywords. Instead date use dat_col or something like that.

```
  select distinct DATEFROMPARTS(year(dt), month(dt), day(dt)) as date_col
           , name
           , min(dt) over(partition by Datepart(dy, dt), name) as first
           , max(dt) over(partition by Datepart(dy, dt), name) as last
           , concat(year(dt), month(dt), day(dt), name) conc_col
    from employees
    where name <> 'noname'
    order by name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CAST(dt AS date)` to get a single date from the date/time value.

Then simply group by that expression. There is no need for `HAVING` or `DISTINCT` or window functions

```sql
select
  CAST(dt AS date) as date,
  name,
  min(dt) as first,
  max(dt) as last
from employees
where name <> 'noname'
group by
  name,
  CAST(dt AS date)
order by
  date,
  name;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e699a26b695703f8745fb770d79acbf2)